# Multiple dropdown menus slide toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have three (or more in the future) dropdown menus that are show when clicked on a 'trigger'

The code is functional but I want the slideUp animation to finish before another slideDown animation begins.

Note that the 'dropdown' elements are positioned absolutely, top:100% in relation to the 'container' so they appear under the 'triggers'

[The code on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoqCh)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="drop-container">
   <span class="trigger">Drop 1</span>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <p>First Dropdown</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="drop-container">
   <span class="trigger">Drop 2</span>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <p>Second dropdown</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="drop-container">
   <span class="trigger">Drop 3</span>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <p>Third dropdown</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $container = $('.drop-container'),
    $trigger = $('.trigger');

$trigger.on('click',function(){

    var $this = $(this).siblings('.dropdown');


    $container.find('.dropdown').slideUp();

    if($this.is(':visible')) {
        $this.hide('fast');
    }

    else {
        $this.slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: jquery animations have a `complete` callback.. see docs for examples

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a delay

```
$this.delay(500).slideDown();
```

but as pointed out it in the comments would be better to use the callback.

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gqram)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without using timers. You can basically add a class to the element that has slide down and use the "oncomplete" property of jQuery slide. Replace your javascript with the below and it should work live example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/agEcz)

```
$container = $('.drop-container')
  $trigger = $('.trigger')
  $trigger.on('click',function(){
  var $drop = $(this).siblings('.dropdown')
  $down = $container.find('.down')
  if($down.length > 0){
    $down.slideUp(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('down')
      $drop.addClass('down')
      $drop.slideDown()
  })
  }
  else{
      $drop.addClass('down')
      $drop.slideDown()
      }

})
```